# What is an equivalent of EXCEPT(in PostgreSQL) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench, sysdba

I want to find out unmatched records of two tables in MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` predicate. Assume you want to mimic:

```
select a.c1, a.c2 from a
except
select b.c1, b.c2 from b
```

This can be expressed as:

```
select distinct a.c1, a.c2 
from a
where not exists (
    select 1 from b
    where b.c1 = a.c1
      and b.c2 = a.c2
)
```

Other options are to use a left join and check for null:

```
select distinct a.c1, a.c2 
from a 
left join b 
    on a.c1 = b.c1 
   and a.c2 = b.c2 
where b.c1 is null
```

Note that these differ from `EXCEPT` if the same tuple exists in both relations and contains null. Let a = {(1,1),(2,2),(1,null)} and b = {(1,1),(1,null)}

```
select a.c1, a.c2 from a 
except 
select b.c1, b.c2 from b

(2,2)
```

In a sense, `EXCEPT` considers null to be equal to null, whereas the predicate a.c2 = b.c2 evaluates to null if either a.c2 or b.c2 is null and as a consequence `NOT EXISTS` evaluates to false.

```
select distinct a.c1, a.c2 
from a 
where not exists (
    select b.c1, b.c2 from b where a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2
)

(2,2),(1,null)
```

`LEFT JOIN` behaves similarly to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct a.c1, a.c2 
from a 
left join b 
    on a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2 
where b.c1 is null

(2,2),(1,null)
```